# Embedding Matplotlib in Tkinter, display problems

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm currently trying to graph a sphere in a tkinter window using matplotlib. How do I go about making the display square? I'd like the sphere to have as little distortion as possible.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  axes3d,Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import Tkinter
import sys

class ElectronOrbitalGenerator(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent


        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.dest)
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        ax = Axes3D(self.fig)

        u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
        v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

        x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
        y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
        z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

        t = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='lightgreen',linewidth=0)

        self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack(padx=15,pady=15)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.frame)

        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)


        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

        self.btn = Tkinter.Button(self,text='button',command=self.alt)
        self.btn.pack()

    def alt (self):
        print 9
    def dest(self):
        self.destroy()
        sys.exit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ElectronOrbitalGenerator(None)
    app.title('Embedding in TK')
    app.mainloop()
```

**EDIT**

I tried

```
    self.fig.set_figwidth(100.0)
    self.fig.set_figheigth(100.0)
```

and got this

```
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'set_figheigth'
```

Comment: I had a typo, it is:set_figheight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `pyplot.figure()`'s `figsize` paramater to set the figure size.

e.g.

`self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the figure size attributes?
fig.set_figwidth and fig.set_figheigh
t